# OpenSSL cipher PSK-AES128-CCM8 is not supported?

Tags: openssl, ubuntu-16.04, tls-psk

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, and `openssl version` returns "OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019"

I would like to use `PSK-AES128-CCM8` in an application but it does not seem to be supported.  It is not returned by `openssl ciphers -s -v ALL` but it is returned by `openssl ciphers  -v ALL`  (None of the PSK ciphers seem to be supported by the way)

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ciphersuite is available in OpenSSL 1.1.1c but you don't get PSK by default with OpenSSL unless you have actually configured a PSK for it to use - hence it does not appear in the "supported" list that is output by the "-s" option. If you additionally pass the "-psk" option then it will configure OpenSSL with a dummy PSK and the "-s" option will start showing PSK ciphers, i.e.

```
openssl ciphers -psk -s -v ALL
```